# Send mails via outlook - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am sending messages via outlook as below
For some reason its working only when the outlook is opened as administrator. this is the only way it could work?

```
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

$email = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$email.To = "info@tekcookie.com"
$email.Subject = "New email test"
$email.Body = "This is a testing email" 
$email.Attachments.add("D:\Files\project-report.pptx")

$email.Send()
$outlook.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not.

Maybe your component services security has some limitations, would it be due policies, acl's or maybe antivirus software.